# What is the difference between md5sum and cksum

Tags: checksum, md5sum

Can someone explain what is the difference between md5sum and cksum, when I compare 2 binary files.

One difference I know is cksum gives the number of "bytes" also along with the checksum value, which md5sum doesn't give.

But my question is to compare 2 binary files, I can chose to use any of these at my will, or they have any specific purposes as well, for specific situations.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 6):

If all you want is to check if 2 specific files are different or not, use `cmp FILE1 FILE2`. It will stop at the first difference encountered, so you don't lose time calculating checksums for the entire file.

If you do need a full checksum :

- `cksum` does a 32 bit ckecksum (CRC-32), while `md5sum` does a "more reliable" 128 bit checksum.
- `cksum` being simpler, it may be faster in some cases, but it may also not be the case because `md5sum` has been highly optimized for speed.
- `cksum` is part of POSIX, and may be present on some systems where `md5sum` is not.

Note that on Mac OS X, `md5sum` is not installed by default, but there is `md5`. The output of `md5 -r` is in the same format as md5sum.

Comment: Mac line breaks are LF, not CR. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

Comment: @Alexander: In theory, yes. In practice, it depends on your version of OS X. I see that in High Sierra it is now indeed LF. But in some previous version I had the problem that it was CR.

Comment: Yes, Mac OS Classic (pre OS 10), which was like 20 years ago now.

Comment: @Alexander: I did mean some (older) version of OS X. (Mac Classic didn't even have a command line). But I can't remember which version gave me this problem.